# Who should have an iterator, my data class or the actual list inside that class?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, stl, iterator

Implementing iterators in real C++ application seems to be quite confusing to say the least. I am implementing this in a demo to understand iterators.

I have AudoDealer class, which has address etc and than it has the an actual list (in my case stl::list) that contains all the cars with that dealer. Now I want an iterator which can iterate through all the cars in that dealership.

First question is that should the concrete-iterator take in the `AutoDealer` class or the actual `list` inside this class which stores the cars? I would like it to take in AutoDealer class because that way it sort of have the ownership of the class and deals with it all together as oppose to an independent iterator which is posing only to an internal part of the structure but later seems better?

The 2nd question is that because I am using STL list class as my container, storing `int currentItem` does't make sense but I should be rather storing `std::list<>iterator` to traverse. Now I can't really get this iterator type to store to begin with! It will break the principle of exposing list implementation.

My code is below, it is still work in progress but everything is below and btw I am following gang of four book.

```
// IteratorDemo.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <class Object>
class Iterator
{
public:
    virtual Object * first();
    virtual Object * next();
    virtual bool IsDone() const  = 0;
    virtual Object * currentItem() const  = 0;
};


class Car
{
    string make;
    string model;
    string price;
    bool isTruck; // if true is truck, otherwise sedan (assume for this example)
};

//template <class Item>
class AutoDealer
{
public:
    AutoDealer();
    virtual ~AutoDealer();

    // create iterator
    //virtual Iterator<item> * CreateIterator() = 0;



    virtual string GetDealerAddress() 
    { 
        return address;
    };
    virtual void SetDealerAddress(string addr)
    {
        address = addr;
    }
    virtual void SetNumberOfSedans() = 0;
    virtual void SetNumberOfTrucks() = 0;

    virtual Car * GetCar() = 0;
    virtual void AddCar(Car car) = 0;

protected:
    string address;

};

//template <class item>
class AutoDealerImpl : public AutoDealer
{
public:
    AutoDealerImpl()
    {
    }
    virtual ~AutoDealerImpl();

/*  virtual Iterator<item> * CreateIterator()
    {
        return std::list<Car>::iterator;
    }
*/

    virtual void SetNumberOfSedans();
    virtual void SetNumberOfTrucks();

    virtual Car * GetCar();
    virtual void AddCar(Car car)
    {
        carList.push_back( car );
    }

protected:
    std::list<Car> carList; // list implementation


};

template <class Object>
class AutoDealerIterator : public Iterator<Object>
{
public:
    AutoDealerIterator( AutoDealer * theDealer )
    {
//      dealer = theDealer;
    }
    virtual Object * first()
    {
    }
    virtual Object * next();
    virtual bool IsDone() const  = 0;
    virtual Object * currentItem() const  = 0;

protected:
    AutoDealer * dealer;
    int _currentItem; // this is an issue, it should be std::list<car>::iterator type here but how can I access that?
                     // I am not traversing a simple list but an STL list which already
                    // has its own iterator and I need that iterator to travese but how do I access it?

};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{



}
```

**Update**

I have another goal from this demo project which can bypass the previous questions.
As I have `CAutoDealer` which is simply the interface and than `AutoDealerImpl` which is concrete. The data members actually reside inside the concrete for encapsulation. How can I iterate through the data using the interface class?

My main objective is to iterate through `std::list<Car>` in my application. Should the `AutoDealer` have this responsibility or iterating this outside the main class is in line with OOP? My goal is a good Object Oriented Design and open to design patterns.

Comment: Iterators belong to collections. An autodealer is not a collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist in having run-time polymorphic iterators you'd have your concrete iterator take a pair of `std::list<Car>::iterator`s in a `private` constructor and you'd make your `AutoDealerImpl` a friend of your `AutoDealerIterator` so it can construct them:

```
class AutoDealerIterator
    : public Iterator<Car>
{
    friend class AutoDealer;
    std::list<Car>::iterator d_begin;
    std::list<Car>::iterator d_it;
    std::list<Car>::iterator d_end;

    AutoDealerIterator(std::list<Car>::iterator begin, std::list<Car>::end)
        : d_begin(begin)
        , d_it(begin)
        , d_end(end)
    {
    }
public:
    Car * first() final { this->d_it = this->d_begin; return this->next(); }
    Car * next() final  { return ++this->d_it == this->d_end? 0: &*this->d_it; }
    bool  IsDone() const final { return this->d_it == this->d_end; }
    Object * currentItem() const final { return &*this->d_it; }
};
```

Creating the actual `AutoDealerIterator` object from an `AutoDealer` should be trivial.

Note that using a run-time polymorphic iterator is generally a bad idea: it doesn't quite work and is also quite likely to be relatively slow. Furthermore it seems that most processing of sequences actually has a concrete idea of the objects it is processing.

Comment: I was struggling with the thought of being object oriented and yet access `std::list<car>` data member of the AutoDealer class outside this class to iterate. Since it already has an iterator so I guess I can already use that outside this class to keep things simpler.

Comment: So your solution does convert from std::list<Car>::iterator to polymophic iterator. However I opted to work directly with std::list operator and I added a function which returns that starting with `carList.begin()` but this doesn't have a function to check if reached the end, does it? It requires the list itself too to actually iterate? Thanks!

Comment: Your iterator interface requires that you can produce the start, a current position, and the end of the list (to know you are done). You can get the start and end from the list, from something knowing the list, or just store them. I had chosen to store the iterators because the iterstor will be slow already with at least one virtual call per element. No need to do a further indirection to burn more cycles.